# How to setup cassandara and kafka authentication at lagom deployment on kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, lagom

I try to deploy a few µServices with lagom and kubernetes.
The kubernetes cluster is ready.
Now my question HOW I config the access to cassandra and kafka.

For cassandra I found out these (application.conf)

is that the correct way and how I configure a kafka (setup on kuberentes) access?

thank you

```
my-service.cassandra {
  authentication {
    username = "some-user"
    password = "some-password"
  }
}

lagom.persistence.read-side.cassandra {
  authentication = ${my-service.cassandra.authentication}
}

cassandra-journal {
  authentication = ${my-service.cassandra.authentication}
}

cassandra-snapshot-store {
  authentication = ${my-service.cassandra.authentication}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right way. A few hours of searching and testing. Start it with external_service _cql._tcp.cassandra.NAME.svc.cluster.local will work